# Problem while merging a specific multi level pivot table back to the orignal (single level) dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My question is related to pivot table and merging.

I have a main dataframe  that I use to create a pivot table. Later, I perform some calculations to that pivot and add a new column. Finally I want to merge this new column back to the main dataframe but not getting result as desired.

I try to explain the steps that i performed as follows:

Step 1.

```
df:

  items cat section  weight factor1
0   1    7   abc      3      80       
1   1    7   abc      3      80
2   2    7   xyz      5      60
3   2    7   xyz      5      60
4   2    7   xyz      5      60
5   2    7   xyz      5      60
6   3    7   abc      3      80
7   3    7   abc      3      80 
8   3    7   abc      3      80

9   1    8   abc      2      80 
10  1    8   abc      2      60
11  2    8   xyz      6      60
12  2    8   xyz      6      60
12  2    8   xyz      6      60
13  2    8   xyz      6      60
14  3    8   abc      2      80

15  1    9   abc      4      80
16  2    9   xyz      9      60
17  2    9   xyz      9      60
18  3    9   abc      4      80
```

Main dataframe (df) having number of items. Each item has given a number.
whereas each item belongs to a dedicated section. Each item has given a weight that varies based on a category (cat) and section. In addition, there is another column named 'factor' whose value is constant for a given section.

Step 2. 
I need to create a pivot as follows from the above df.

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(db, index=['section'],values=['weight','factor', 'items'],columns=['cat'],aggfunc={'weight':np.max,'factor':np.max, 'items':np.sum})

pivot:
          weight       factor      items 
cat     7   8   9    7   8    9    7  8  9
section
abc     3   2   4    80  80   80   5  3  2
xyz     5   6   9    60  60   60   4  4  2
```

Step 3:
Now I want to perform some calculations on that pivot then add the
result in a new column as follows:

```
pivot['w_n',7] = pivot['factor', 7]/pivot['items', 7]
pivot['w_n',8] = pivot['factor', 8]/pivot['items', 8]
pivot['w_n',9] = pivot['factor', 9]/pivot['items', 9]

pivot:
          weight       factor      items       w_n
cat     7   8   9    7   8    9    7  8  9    7  8   9
section
abc     3   2   4    80  80   80   5  3  2   16  27  40 
xyz     5   6   9    60  60   60   4  4  2   15  15  30
```

Step 4:
Finally I want to merge that new column back to the main df .
with a desired result of single column 'w_n' but instead I am getting 3 columns one for each cat.

```
Current result:
df:
  items cat section  weight factor1   w_n_7  w_n,8  w_n,9
0   1    7   abc      3      80         16    27    40
1   1    7   abc      3      80         16    27    40
2   2    7   xyz      5      60         15    15    30
3   2    7   xyz      5      60         15    15    30
4   2    7   xyz      5      60         15    15    30
5   2    7   xyz      5      60         15    15    30
6   3    7   abc      3      80         16    27    40
7   3    7   abc      3      80         16    27    40
8   3    7   abc      3      80         16    27    40

9   1    8   abc      2      80         16    27    40
10  1    8   abc      2      60         16    27    40
11  2    8   xyz      6      60         15    15    30
12  2    8   xyz      6      60         15    15    30
12  2    8   xyz      6      60         15    15    30
13  2    8   xyz      6      60         15    15    30
14  3    8   abc      2      80         16    27    40

15  1    9   abc      4      80         16    27    40
16  2    9   xyz      9      60         15    15    30
17  2    9   xyz      9      60         15    15    30
18  3    9   abc      4      80         16    27    40
```

```
Desired result:
------------------
df:
  items cat section  weight factor1    w_n
0   1    7   abc      3      80         16
1   1    7   abc      3      80         16 
2   2    7   xyz      5      60         15
3   2    7   xyz      5      60         15
4   2    7   xyz      5      60         15
5   2    7   xyz      5      60         15
6   3    7   abc      3      80         16
7   3    7   abc      3      80         16
8   3    7   abc      3      80         16

9   1    8   abc      2      80         27
10  1    8   abc      2      60         27
11  2    8   xyz      6      60         15
12  2    8   xyz      6      60         15
12  2    8   xyz      6      60         15
13  2    8   xyz      6      60         15
14  3    8   abc      2      80         27

15  1    9   abc      4      80         40
16  2    9   xyz      9      60         30
17  2    9   xyz      9      60         30
18  3    9   abc      4      80         40
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `MultiIndex Series` with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.join(pivot['w_n'].unstack().rename('W_n'), on=['cat','section'])
print (df)
    items  cat section  weight  factor        W_n
0       1    7     abc       3      80   7.272727
1       1    7     abc       3      80   7.272727
2       2    7     xyz       5      60   7.500000
3       2    7     xyz       5      60   7.500000
4       2    7     xyz       5      60   7.500000
5       2    7     xyz       5      60   7.500000
6       3    7     abc       3      80   7.272727
7       3    7     abc       3      80   7.272727
8       3    7     abc       3      80   7.272727
9       1    8     abc       2      80  16.000000
10      1    8     abc       2      60  16.000000
11      2    8     xyz       6      60   7.500000
12      2    8     xyz       6      60   7.500000
12      2    8     xyz       6      60   7.500000
13      2    8     xyz       6      60   7.500000
14      3    8     abc       2      80  16.000000
15      1    9     abc       4      80  20.000000
16      2    9     xyz       9      60  15.000000
17      2    9     xyz       9      60  15.000000
18      3    9     abc       4      80  20.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I am getting an error while merging:ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat. Like to mention that the data i am testing on is different then the one I use in the example.